# CSS: Browser shows a different color code than the one set on CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, colors, background-color

I have a div with the property:

```
background-color: #327EB2;
```

When I open the page on a browser I notice that a different color is shown. If I capture the screen and open the captured image on Photoshop, I can see that the color code captured is actually #437BB6. I have nothing set with that color in my CSS stylesheet.

I've tested on different monitors, different color resolutions, different browsers and versions from FF 4+ to IE8+, Opera, Chrome, Safari, etc...

Actually I don't think that's a problem of the monitor, resolution or browser version, because the problem is that the code of the shown color is actually a totally different one!

Also, Photoshop warns me about #327EB2 which is not a "Web Safe color", but I don't think this is the problem because I often use non-websafe colors in my sheets and I've never had an issue like that.

** Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/286tE/

*UPDATE

The problem is that the div has a background image and a background-color. The background color has to match the last pixel's color of the background image (as usual), which is #327EB2.
Anyway, I can see a different color from the last pixel of the image to the background-color:

http://test.testblueday.eu/test/cbsissue.png

You can see the page here, the problem is shown after the "Top Marchi" list on the left side:

http://test.testblueday.eu/test/cbstest.html

I've left the plain CSS and JS (not compressed) to let you see all the properties.

** UPDATE 2

I use Mac, but we can see the problem also on Windows.

Comment: Can you put it in a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: Monitors doesn't change the hex :p

Comment: Open Developer Tools (F12, in Firefox you may need to setup firebug) and inspect element you are talking about. In Chrome, for intance, you will see all styles applied to element being inspected. It will show you if it is overriden by some other style or your css is not updated.

Comment: @Bhushan Firake: It's not a cache issue because I've never used the #437BB6 color and if I open the page on a browser I've never opened with, the problem is the same. Additionally, I've disabled the cache cause I'm developing and I even erased it.

Comment: make sure it is indeed using that hex in your CSS, I just tried it in a fiddle, and both colours are reproduced correctly I checked: (top is the ok, and the bottom is the one you're getting) http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/45uQ5/

Comment: @Mr. Alien: I know, it's kinda strange actually... :)

Comment: @FAngel: I don't have any property with the color #437BB6, anyway Firebug doesn't show me any other style than the one I've written in the CSS with #327EB2 color.

Comment: Maybe you should show your page. It loosk very strange. What about something like transparent element overlaying your div?

Comment: BTW, turn off the colour correction in Photoshop or use some other tool to check the colour rendered in the browser and if that doesn't change any thing, please share the example in a fiddle or similar, and we will check that.

Comment: If it's happening everywhere (browser/system), it's likely indicates that it's related to actual HTML/CSS/JS.  Do you have any Javascript on the page?  Does it work if JavaScript is off?

Comment: I've updated the question with the page that has the problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jackJoe I've checked your Fiddle (thank you btw). If I capture the screen on Photoshop, I can see #437BB6 on the upper div and #4E77B9 on the lower one. It's not a problem of Photoshop color handling, anyway, because if I put my background image over the divs you prepared on the fiddle, I can see the color difference.

Comment: So, the problem is that when background image ends, further space colored with `#327EB2` is not consitent with background-image color, right? And that applies to `.embosser` css class

Comment: @FAngel Exactly. The CSS tells the "div.embosser" to take #327EB2 as background color, but a different one is applied. From the web page I posted on my question, you can download the complete CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You problem has nothing to do with the CSS, the problem is in the image!

This is because the examples supplied by you show the correct #327EB2 at the extra background (the one "coloured" via CSS), and that is enough to know that the CSS part is ok.

Beware of colour corrections/management done in the file exported via Photoshop.

If you can't colour manage/revert to the desired colour, another solution is doing the opposite, change the CSS colour to match the last row of the image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't know what's wrong on Photoshop. Here are all the steps. I have the original PSD image, and the last pixels row has #327EB2 color. I export the JPG, open it with Photoshop: last pixels row is #327EB2. I capture the screen with the issued page, open the captured image with Photoshop, and I see that the last pixels row of the background image is #327EB2, but the background color is #437BB6 (http://test.testblueday.eu/test/cbsissue.png). So, if the exported JPG has wrong colors, shouldn't I see them when I re-open the JPG or open the screen capture image?

Comment: @tobia.zanarella Photoshop has a "nice" colour management but it will do that to your colours, turn it off and you'll see the colour ok, unless it was incorrect already before exporting. Make this test: turn off the colour management and create a block of colour with the right hex, export it and reopen it, place it in the site, etc and check its colours. Also try this tool to check your colours anywhere: http://www.charcoaldesign.co.uk/pipette

Comment: Thank you! Actually, disabling Photoshop's color settings (or, better, using "North America Web/Internet" color settings (I couldn't find a "no color management" option, but that one worked like a charm), and opening the images with the working color profile instead of the embedded one, it shows me the correct hex colors!! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @tobia.zanarella I've been there :) I switched it off completely in CS4. Glad it was solved.

Comment: LOL I'm a developer, not a graphic! That's the reason :) 3 hours lost just for a color profile... Anyway, thank you again very much.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, everything works correctly. Your image at the bottom has color with code '#1080b3' - I just downloaded that picture (`gradient_box_emboss.jpg`) and took a color with colorpicker in GIMP. When I modify css like this:

```
.embosser {
   background: #1080B3 url('/images/gradient_box_emboss.jpg') right top no-repeat;
   color: white;
   padding: 5px 6px;
}
```

Difference is missing. When I printscreen your site and paste it into GIMP, color picker shows color of that "wrong" background is `#327eb2`. When I open your image you have in your question, color of background is  `#307db7`. It is in jpg and I suppose some color information were lost while compressing raw data to .jpg. Possibly, something similar happens when you are trying to get color in photoshop.

Possibly problem rise when you convert images from one format to another.  Simplest fix is above - change color of background to one you have on your image.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, disabling Photoshop's color settings (or, better, using "North America Web/Internet" color settings, and opening the images with the working color profile instead of the embedded one, it shows me the correct hex colors!! Thank you for your help!
#107FB3 is the one.